# How to copy and paste values in another worksheet using transpose and loop it

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, transpose

I have been having trouble in copy pasting a range of cells (vertically) to another worksheet which should display horizontally. And also using a spin button to determine how many times it will loop to copy the data.

This is my single line of code to copy and transpose, I only get the error in "Transpose:=True"
The error is

> Compiler Expected: error element

I only follow YouTube tutorials and I just combine my code.

`Range("D3:D10").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`

And this is my code for the spin button that will determine how many times it will copy and paste to the other worksheet. Cell G7 will determine the number of times it will copy to the other worksheet

```
    With Range("G7")
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(.Value - 1)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
    With Range("G7")
    .Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Value + 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: insert a comma before `Transpose:=True`, i.e.: `Range("D3:D10").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial, Transpose:=True`

Comment: I tried this before but it just displays another error
"Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: split it into two lines: line 1) `Range("D3:D10").Copy` ; line 2) `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True`

Comment: It worked! thank you, I didnt know that splitting it in two lines are important, my only problem now is the looping part.

Comment: or keep statements in one line but separate them by a colon, i.e.: `Range("D3:D10").Copy: Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True`

Comment: BTW what are those `.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Value + 1)` doing there? Shouldn't `.Value = .Value + 1` suffice?

Comment: I just followed the code from the internet

Comment: _"I didnt know that splitting it in two lines are important"_: it's because there are two different statements: the `Copy` one and the `PasteSpecial` one. And different statements must be in different lines  or be separated by a colon

Comment: _"I just followed the code from the internet"_: and did the internet example have that `With Range("G7")`, too? Anyway, try without `WorksheetFunction.Max`

Comment: It displays an error "Sub or Function not defined"

Comment: are you just changing `.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Value + 1)` to `.Value = .Value + 1` ?

Comment: It worked now! Sorry I misunderstood and did not remove the commas. But its not an issue to me. I need it for the looping.